# how to capture ssl traffic using SharpPcap

Tags: ssl, sniffing, sharppcap

SharpPcap is a great library. I'm building http packet viewer for linux using it and it works fine! However is it possible to capture and decrypt ssl traffic? From one hand it would be exactly what ssl is designed against and so I would say the answer is no. On the other hand I see things like PacketDotNet.LinuxSLLPacket which give hope. So is this possible and if so where could I get some info on how to do this?

Comment: Not sure about SharpPcap but if you have the certificate file, it is possible through Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org). It does exactly what you want it to do.

The way it works is by allowing you to set your proxy settings to mitmproxy running on 8080 by default. You install the certificate for the mitmproxy on your machine, phone, browser and it will essentially provide you with a man-in-the-middle.